# OPC UA command modeling

Tags: python, iot, opc-ua

I'm currently looking at `OPC UA` for setting up a sensor network, and intended to do the following.

- Each sensor runs an `OPC UA server` having a custom sensor model.
- Clients can query the sensor. I'm using an open source python implementation for the client and the server.(https://github.com/FreeOpcUa)

At the time being, the sensor values can be read and it works fine.

The problem is that some of my sensors also accepts commands, so in a sense they can become actors as well. For instance, a sensor can have different reading-modes. I can change these modes by giving it an change-command. The control-unit `"client"` accesses the sensor `"server"`.

My question is that:

1. How can I model commands with `OPC UA`?
2. I would like to use methods on the sensor `"server"`. Can I generate on the sensor an `OPC UA` event through a method call?

Has somebody done something similar than this with OPC UA? I would love to hear your suggestions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1) Modeling the commands with Methods seems like an appropriate use case to me.

2) There's no reason that invocation of a method on `server` couldn't result in an event firing on `server` as well. Go for it. In fact, the spec explicitly mentions that method nodes can have `GeneratesEvent` and `AlwaysGeneratesEvent` references.